# Chrome is using a cached page when local-serving for web-development

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a node.js local server to serve Chrome a three.js page, and Chrome instead of updating the page when I reload it after I've done some changes, it reloads a cached version instead, and will only update it after I clear all history, then close and re-open the dumb Chrome, which is extremely frustrating and inefficient. That doesn't happen with Firefox. Any ideas?

```
node.js server run on a .bat file inside the working folder: 
http-server -p 8000
exit

on address bar:
http://localhost:8000/mypage.html
```

Comment: You can use ctrl+f5 to force a reload ignoring the cache

Comment: Thanks, it worked and is simple enough!

Comment: Also, you can use the _development tools_ and disable cache from there (it's a checkbox on network tab).